# Is there any way to access Firebase from an App Engine servlet without using manual scaling or the flexible environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Question:

Is there any way to access Firebase using server-side code without using either manual scaling or the flexible environment?

Context:

I want to achieve the following flow:
app posts pending 'updates' to firebase -> backend picks them up -> backend sends emails -> backend modifies firebase 'updates' to non-pending state

From what I can see, if I want the back end to pick these updates up in real time, I need a long-running thread in the App Engine Flexible Environment. I'm prepared to forego this to avoid the flexible environment's pricing model and beta status.

Given that my choice is therefore the App Engine Standard Environment, it appears that to access Firebase i'm stuck with having to enable manual scaling.

It seems madness to have a resident instance running all the time - when there's no requirement to listen to updates in real time - which sits idle for 95% of the time then isn't available outside of a 9-instance-hour (free) contiguous period.

Can Firebase be somehow accessed from a server-side without 'attaching a listener', such that I can call it from an automatically scaled instance and simply get a snapshot? If not, is there an alternate technical or architectural solution here - or something I'm missing?

This must be a fairly common issue!

Thankyou for your time, much appreciated.

Comment: Using the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) perhaps?